# An application that hosts a set of other applications

Tags: android, android-widget

I have half a dozen apps that i want to put on Google Market. One of them are ready and the other are in progress. All these apps are kinda related - like a suite of apps, you could assume. So, i was wondering if it would be better to have a separate app (in addition from the half a dozen apps i wish to develop) and have it serve as a LIBRARY-app where users can find, purchase and launch the half a dozen apps.

This is conceptually similar to the Google Books free app where the app serves as a library and users can browse for other books from within this app and purchase it. The only difference is in my case, it would be other fully functional independent app instead of a book.

Is there a better way to approach what i am trying to do? Basically, i need an app that can host a set of mutually independent apps.

If yes, how do i "host" one app inside an app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer (atleast the one that suits my situation the best) can be found here -

[Answer On Google Developers fourm](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/28d2e4264440a905?hl=en)